# Cannot open Windows! in Ubuntu/Windows dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I tried installing Windows/Ubuntu a while back, but I kind of gave up using Windows because I couldn't solve my problem. Right now, I'm just using Ubuntu, but I do see windows section when i do gparted. But now i need to use VBA.

Can someone please help me to boot with Windows?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15582491/

best,
Jae Woo

Comment: what is meant by VBA?

Comment: The partition on which Windows is installed was not bootable as per the pastebin report. Moro ever there are some disk read errors also.

Comment: Thank you Ashu. I meant Visual Basics. Can you guide me to what I need to do? I'm quite clueless.

Comment: You can run VB on Ubuntu. See the Mono project.

Comment: Good to know. thank you. Is there a way to upvote your answers?

Comment: Comments could be upvoted while hovering the cursor on the comment, then click to ^ image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no entry in the grub menu pointing to windows partition, sda3. There are a ton of linux versions though! Look at your pastebin starting at line 285.

Try rebuilding your grub. use [boot repair](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/reinstall-recover-grub-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd-usb/)

Answer (score 0):

These are the Win partitions, you just need to run `sudo update-grub`, and if it finds the Win installation, then just boot there, save files, reboot.

```
/dev/sda2         534,528       567,295        32,768 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda3         567,296    98,080,831    97,513,536 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda4     349,603,840   351,651,839     2,048,000 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda7     333,002,752   333,072,383        69,632 EFI System partition
```